# Assign signs with passive sign convention in transient analysis

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, transient

It's known that most books prefer the usage of passive sign convention and recommends to set polarities to all schematic elements before writing KVL equations. But how to proper set signs in schematic that is used for transient analysis like below? One polarity is set and one current direction is set ("i"). The second was selected by me? But what about signs on nodes of elements. In this situation I must properly identify which capacitor is a consumer (C1 - I think) and which is a power source (I think it's C2). What about initial voltage on capacitors, how the schematic would be if I add two voltage sources that represents initial voltages on capacitors and how to properly setup the polarities on them? It's all I need to write the proper KVL differential equation to solve the transient response. Any suggestions, please?

[image]

Comment: **"In this situation I must properly identify which capacitor is a consumer (C1 - I think) and which is a power source (I think it's C2)"** ... no you don't need to do that. Just make sure that KCL is obeyed. If you choose the 'wrong' direction, the current will come out of the analysis with a negative sign. The whole point of the analysis is to find **unknown** currents and voltages, and the direction of a current is one of those unknowns.

Comment: There are different ways to assign signs in these loops, and in superposition. Find one that works for you, and stick to it. Applying your sign rules *has to be consistent*. Then practice, practice....this is one place where doing plenty of assignments pays off.

Comment: @glen_geek May you provide any link to good assignment algorithm appropriate for my circuit and "good" in your opinion?

Comment: An opinion from a twisted brain like mine won't do **you** much good - to be honest, I still have trouble with these sign assignments!